# How to stop the media player properly

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

How do I stop the media player in fragment activity with `pageradapter` when the user clicks on the back button?

Every time I click the back button, the audio is still playing.

```
package com.androidbasedcollectionofstories;

import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class BRUSH1 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
            @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.brushing1,container,false);
        ImageView imageview = (ImageView) view.findViewById (R.id.imageView1);
        if(imageview == null) throw new AssertionError();
        imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animbrushing1);
        AnimationDrawable anim = (AnimationDrawable)imageview.getBackground();
        anim.start();

        final MediaPlayer sound=MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.brushingtitle);
        sound.start();
        return view;
    }

}
```

Comment: create a mediaplayer object outside the  onCreateView and use sound.stop() and sound.release() in overrided onStop() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to stop media player, then you can stop in `onDestroyView` method.

```
public class BRUSH1 extends Fragment {

    MediaPlayer sound;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.brushing1,container,false);
        ImageView imageview = (ImageView) view.findViewById (R.id.imageView1);
        if(imageview == null) throw new AssertionError();
        imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animbrushing1);
        AnimationDrawable anim = (AnimationDrawable)imageview.getBackground();
        anim.start();

        sound = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.brushingtitle);
        sound.start();
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        if (sound != null) {
            sound.stop();
            sound.release();
        }
        super.onDestroyView();
    }

}
```

Comment: it helps sir thanks a lot but when i swipe the page the sound is now overlapping

Comment: Use Fragment's childFragmentManager instead of fragmentManager to construct the FragmentStatePagerAdapter. only then those onPause and onStop of child Fragments inside ViewPager will be called.

Comment: i am not using a ViewPager sir I am using fragment activity and PagerAdapter

Comment: What are you using PagerAdapter on? It must be viewPager right? you might have some code like viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter) where you have created PagerAdapter.. Have a closer look at it..

Comment: i don't know how to use viewPager..Here is my code for PagerAdapter.. PagerAdapterBRUSH extends FragmentPagerAdapter

Comment: UseFragmentStatePagerAdapter instead of FragmentPagerAdapter

Comment: I think it will become a very long thread here, if your problem is still not fixed, contact me here https://mobile.twitter.com/erluxman

Comment: you can't be message you sir here is mine https://mobile.twitter.com/emey38615117

Comment: sir can i get your email ?